# Compute $\gcd(a+b, 2a+3b)$ if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

A question from a problem set is asking to compute the value of $\gcd(a+b, 2a+3b)$ if $\gcd(a+b) = 1$, or if it isn't possible, prove why.

Here's how I ended up doing it:

$\gcd(a,b) = 1$ implies that for some integers $x$, and $y$, that $ax+by = 1$.

Let $d = gcd(a+b, 2a+3b)$. This implies:

$\implies \text{d is divisible into }2(2a+3b) - 4(a+b) = 2b\cdots    (1)$

$\implies \text{d is divisible into} 6(a+b) - 2(2a+3b) = 2a\cdots       (2)$

Statement $(1)$ implies that $d$ divides $2by$ for some integer $y$

Statement $(2)$ implies that $d$ divides $2ax$ for some integer $x$

This implies that $d$ is divisible into $2(ax+by)$, which implies:

$\gcd(a+b, 2a+3b) =\text{ either 1 or 2}$

Thus the result is not generally determinable as it takes $2$ possible values.

Are my assumptions and logic correct? If not, where are the errors?

Thank you!

Comment: Actually $d  \mid (2a+3b)-\color{red}{2}(a+b)=b$ likewise  $d  \mid \color{red}{3}(a+b)-(2a+3b)=a$, thus $d \mid \gcd(a,b)=1$. Thus $d=1$.

Comment: @AnuragA sorry if this is a dumb question, but why is it not appropriate to use 2(2a+3b) - 4(a+b), and accurate to instead use (2a+3b) - 2(a+b)?

Comment: it is not incorrect to use any multiplier. But we want to go for those multipliers which might give us the best possible conclusion. With your choices the best you can conclude is that $d \mid 2\gcd(a,b)=2$. This means either $d=1$ or $d=2$. However, in this case, the answer happens to be $1$ so that means your choice of the multiplier was not enough to come to the required conclusion.

Comment: wording:  usually we say $m$ divides $n$ or $n$ is divisible by $m$

Comment: @AnuragA I'm not sure if I understand what you're getting at. If I can conclude that d∣2gcd(a,b)=2, then would d not be able to be both 1 and 2? I'm just not realizing why it can only be 1.

Comment: I am not Anurag, but I'll try to explain. GaryCong, your conclusion is that the _possible_ answers are 1 and 2. And your conclusion is correct. Anurag's conclusion says that the _possible_ answer is 1. And his(her) conclusion is correct. Now we "join" both conclusions and the result is that the only possible answer is 1. (The number 2 cannot be the answer because Anurag's conclusion discarded it.)

Comment: @GaryCong imagine you could have done the following: $d  \mid 5(2a+3b)-\color{red}{15}(a+b)=-5a$ and $d  \mid 5(2a+3b)-\color{red}{10}(a+b)=5b$, then this would mean $d \mid 5\gcd(a,b)=5$, so you could have concluded that $d=1,5$. This means $d \neq 2$. Consequently, with your choice of multipliers you are only getting partial information about $d$.

Comment: Ah okay, I got it! Thanks to everyone for the help :)

Comment: *Hint*: $$\gcd(a+b,2a+3b)=\gcd(a+b,2a+3b-2(a+b))=\gcd(a+b,b)=\gcd(a,b)=1$$

Comment: GaryCong, as JWTanner said, please edit your post to change "is divisible into" to simply "divides". @AnuragA , FWIW, if you write an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @evaristegd Thanks but I think OP has already understood the concept so I am okay with it.

Comment: @Bach That isn't a hint, that is a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple if you use matrices. Suppose a positive integer $d$ divides both $a + b$ and $2a + 3b$. This can be restated as $d$ dividing both entries of the vector

\begin{equation}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
Multiplying on the left by the inverse matrix, which has integer coefficients, $d$ must therefore also divide each entry of
\begin{equation}\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ -2 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}=\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
Thus $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$ and hence is $1$. Thus $gcd(a+b,2a + 3b) = 1$.